# Vba built in function for holidays during a year?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

So basically i have two tables. A date table and a statHoliday table. The statholiday table has like all the holidays you can find in this country which is fine.

- I auto-populate myDate table to get every monday which is not a
  stat-holiday.
- I delete everything from myDate table before I repopulate everything using auto-execute everytime the database is opened.
- Though it works fine, I am looking for a more efficient way to do this. I think delete everything from table and updating over the years will take time.
- Is there any built functions for holidays in vba?

mydate table looks like this:

```
the_date
---------
08-01-2015
15-01-2015
22-01-2015
29-01-2015

//stat-holiday table
name     | Date
---------------------
New Year | 01-01-2015
Christmas| 25-12-2015
```

my function is below:

```
Function dateTblUpdate()

  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  Dim dt As Date
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Dim sqlS As String

  sqlS = "Select Date as holi from statHolidaysTbl"

  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlS)

  DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM [date-table]"
  For dt = #1/1/2010# To DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
      If Weekday(dt) = 2 Then
         Do While Not rs.EOF 
            If rs!holi <> dt Then
                DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert into [date-table] (the_date) values(#" & dt & "#)"
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
         Loop
         rs.MoveFirst
       End If
   Next
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

Comment: If your code works as expected and you're looking for better, cleaner and/or more efficient ways to code it, you might be interested in [codereview.se] :)

Comment: You should not need to reload `date-table` every time.  Use a query to `LEFT JOIN` the dates table to the holidays table.  Then the Mondays you want are in the query rows where `statHolidaysTbl.Date Is Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are not built-in VBA functions for holidays.  You must use a customized approach to deal with your organization's chosen holidays.

In your current approach, you discard the contents of *[date-table]* and then reload it with the dates of Mondays which are not holidays.

I think it should be simpler to leave *all* the Monday dates in *[date-table]* and use a query which returns only the non-holiday Mondays.  You can accomplish that by `LEFT JOIN`ing *[date-table]* to *statHolidaysTbl* and asking for only those candidate rows where the right side (the holiday date) is Null.

Save this as *qryMondays*:

```sql
SELECT d.the_date
FROM
    [date-table] AS d
    LEFT JOIN statHolidaysTbl AS h
    ON d.the_date = h.Date
WHERE h.Date Is Null;
```

Then wherever you formerly used *[date-table]*, use *qryMondays* instead.

When you need to add more recent Monday dates to *[date-table]*, just add them.  The query will automatically exclude the Monday holidays (assuming you also keep *statHolidaysTbl* updated).  But do not "freshen" *[date-table]* by discarding everything from it and then adding all the Mondays from scratch.  That would be unnecessary work and would bloat the database for no good reason.